# Google API DotNet Youtube playlist list fails with no PlaylistID

Tags: .net, youtube, google-api-dotnet-client

Thank you, I really appreciate your help!

I am trying to get the .NET Google API Client to work, but I can't figure out how to do even the simple things. My Goal is to have a web page that loads a youtube playlist player at the top and just lists info about the other tracks below it.

Can you please help me to get over the first hump of just getting the client to run?

I have a .NET 4.0 website instance and I've installed the DotNet Google API through the nuget package manager. I think the problem is that I can't figure out how to pass the PlaylistID to the client request. Where in the code below can I specify the PlaylistID?

```
Imports Google.Apis.YouTube.v3
Imports Google.Apis.YouTube.v3.Data

Dim Initialiser As New Google.Apis.Services.BaseClientService.Initializer()
Initialiser.ApiKey = "My Server API Key"
Dim Service As YouTubeService = New YouTubeService(Initialiser)
Dim Result As PlaylistItemListResponse
Result = Service.PlaylistItems().List("snippet").Execute()
If Not Result.Items Is Nothing Then
    Dim XPathDocument As System.Xml.XPath.XPathDocument = GenerateXPathDocument(Result.Items)
    SamplerXml.XPathNavigator = XPathDocument.CreateNavigator
End If
```

The Error output is:

```
2014-01-21 12:14:30.1894 Error ASP.global_asax 
Application_Error: GET /sampler/120
BaseExceptionType: Google.GoogleApiException
  Type=System.Web.HttpUnhandledException
  Message=Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown.
  Stack=
at System.Web.UI.Page.HandleError(Exception e)
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestWithNoAssert(HttpContext context)
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
at ASP.templates_sampler_default_aspx.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)

Type=Google.GoogleApiException
Message=Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError
No filter selected. [400]
Errors [
    Message[No filter selected.] Location[ - parameter] Reason[missingRequiredParameter] Domain[youtube.parameter]
]

Stack=
at Google.Apis.Requests.ClientServiceRequest`1.Execute() in c:\code\google.com\google-api-dotnet-client\default\Tools\Google.Apis.Release\bin\Debug\output\default\Src\GoogleApis\Apis\Requests\ClientServiceRequest.cs:line 93
at SiteCode.Templates.Sampler.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\svn-work\playlistproject\site\templates\sampler\Default.aspx.vb:line 54
at System.EventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, EventArgs e)
at System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
```

Thank you for your help and your time!

Answer (score 0):

The answer turned out to be simple.

```
        Dim Initialiser As New Google.Apis.Services.BaseClientService.Initializer()
        Initialiser.ApiKey = "My API Key"
        Dim Service As Google.Apis.YouTube.v3.YouTubeService = New YouTubeService(Initialiser)
        Dim Result As Google.Apis.YouTube.v3.Data.PlaylistItemListResponse
        Dim ListRequest As Google.Apis.YouTube.v3.PlaylistItemsResource.ListRequest
        ListRequest = Service.PlaylistItems().List("snippet")
        ListRequest.PlaylistId = "My Playlist ID"
        Result = ListRequest.Execute()
        If Not Result.Items Is Nothing Then
            Dim XPathDocument As System.Xml.XPath.XPathDocument = GenerateXPathDocument(Result.Items)
            SamplerXml.XPathNavigator = XPathDocument.CreateNavigator
        End If
```

So I had to create the List Request, then set the playlist ID, then execute the request. Sometimes I can be really slow...

I hope this helps someone else!